# Creating the perfect ginger bug?

Tags: fermentation, recipe, ginger-beer, ginger

Can anyone suggest the best recipe for making a ginger bug?

I understand that it is just ginger root and unrefined sugar, but is it better to use organic ginger (if so why?), what is the best sugar to use (I understand that some of it comes down to personal taste)?

Comment: Organic is always better with any sort of fermentation, because it won't contain many of the pesticides that would prevent or hinder fermentation.  Sort of the same reason you don't want to use chlorinated water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it better to use organic ginger

That depends on a lot of factors but [organic produce](http://www.organic-center.org/reportfiles/Taste2Pager.pdf) seems to have better taste than conventional produce.

As to what kind of sugar it entirely depends on what color you want the liquid to have and the taste.

Here's a good [ginger bug recipe](http://nourishedkitchen.com/ginger-bug/)

> 1. Break off a knob from your hand of ginger, peel away its papery skin and grate it until you have 2 heaping tablespoons. Place the grated ginger in a small jar, whisk in 2 tablespoons unrefined cane sugar and 2 tablespoons filtered water. Cover the jar loosely and allow it to ferment in a warm spot in your kitchen.
> 2. Every day for at least 5 days, mix an additional 2 tablespoons grated ginger, 2 tablespoons sugar and 2 tablespoons water into your jar. The ginger will begin to foam and bubble at its top, and will take on the yeasty fragrance of beer. After 5 days, it is ready to use. You can also store it in the refrigerator, and feed it 2 tablespoons grated ginger, 2 tablespoons sugar and 2 tablespoons water once a week.
> 3. To use the ginger bug to make homemade sodas, prepare 1 quart of herbal tea sweetened with a caloric sweetener like sugar (or substitute 1 scoop Body Ecology's Ecobloom). Strain off 1/4 cup of the ginger bug's liquid and whisk it into the sweetened tea. Replace the 1/4 cup ginger bug you've removed with 1/4 cup sugar dissolved into 1/4 cup water. Transfer the sweetened tea and ginger bug to flip-top bottles (available here), and allow it to ferment at room temperature for 3 days. Transfer to the fridge or drink straight away.

If you want to ferment it for making root beer. You just need to add more water and sugar after you've made your initial ginger bug.
Check out [homedistiller](http://homedistiller.org/sugar/wash-sugar/yield) for how much sugar you need.

> To make 25L of wash at 5% alcohol use 2.125kg of sugar